# How can i search for the Image that was given in Binary format and if exists i would like to display the data in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

If any user gives the information of his photo in  binary objects how can i search it and how can i display the corresponding image that was stored in the sql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to create a CRC/Hash of the Image File and then just search for this number. If you found it then compare the full Binary Format to be 100% that is the same.

To display the image I suggest to create an .ashx handler, that you send the ID of the image encrypted, then inside the handler you read the Image from the database and send to an img anchor.

eg.

```
<img src="MyImageHandler.ashx?Id=7738akj12391723">
```

I found some existing examples for display the image from the Database

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Retrieving-Images-from-a-Database--C---Part-II/

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-images-gridview-from-database.html

Its the same as I say...

Comment: Can i have a detailed example on this

Comment: Hey thanks for the links i got it as the way from csharpdotnetfreak